# Can I get both contents and commit data for files?

Tags: github, github-api

I am trying to use GitHub as a CMS for static markdown files since I thought it'd be the simplest integration, plus it's free. Getting the contents is relatively easy as GitHub has a [REST API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents) for this, and I'm able to get the markdown contents via the `download_url` returned. So that part works fine.

However, I'd like to also be able to get the commit data for the file, so I know it's last date of change instead of putting data manually in the Markdown via frontmatter. I've also tried using their GraphQL explorer tool, but it has the same data available more or less. The contents API also returns a `sha` for each of the files in the repo, but I'm not sure how it correlates as querying with their [commits API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/commits/commits) results in nothing being found. Anyone else ever tried anything similar or have a solution?

Here is the GQL query I've tried as well:

```gql
{
  repository(owner: "[OWNER]", name: "[REPO]") {
    object(expression: "main:[FOLDER-PATH]") {
      ... on Tree {
        entries {
          name
          object {
            commitUrl
            ... on Blob {
              text
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `commitUrl` returned here also returns a 404 even when requested with a token.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you call the "Get repository content" endpoint, it returns this JSON body:

```json
{
  "type": "file",
  "encoding": "base64",
  "size": 5362,
  "name": "README.md",
  "path": "README.md",
  "content": "encoded content ...",
  "sha": "3d21ec53a331a6f037a91c368710b99387d012c1",
  "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octokit/octokit.rb/contents/README.md",
  "git_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octokit/octokit.rb/git/blobs/3d21ec53a331a6f037a91c368710b99387d012c1",
  "html_url": "https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb/blob/master/README.md",
  "download_url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/octokit/octokit.rb/master/README.md",
  "_links": {
    "git": "https://api.github.com/repos/octokit/octokit.rb/git/blobs/3d21ec53a331a6f037a91c368710b99387d012c1",
    "self": "https://api.github.com/repos/octokit/octokit.rb/contents/README.md",
    "html": "https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb/blob/master/README.md"
  }
}
```

You can use the `sha` property to call the "Get a commit" API endpoint. (https://docs.github.com/en/rest/commits/commits#get-a-commit)

Your call would look something like this given the above example:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/[REPO-OWNER]/[REPO-NAME]/commits/3d21ec53a331a6f037a91c368710b99387d012c1
```

This will return a JSON response that has the details of the commit associated with the file contents you pulled in the previous API call.

Comment: That's what I assumed but the API returns a 422 ` 
Validation failed, or the endpoint has been spammed`. Have tried via curl and Postman appending my token.

Comment: Make sure you are properly authenticated and are passing the `Accept: application/vnd.github+json` header value. Also double check your the URL you are trying to call too and that it is an HTTP GET.

Comment: I've verified all of that. What I think is the issue is when running `git cat-file -t [sha_from_contents]` I get the return value of blob. But when passing in a commit sha from a commit URL from the web UI I'll get commit as the return. So essentially, I think the sha reference in the API response isn't compatible with the commits API since it represents a hash of the data not the commit itself. I was hoping for a cleaner way, but I can use the `https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/commits?path=FILE_PATH` endpoint instead.